# Creating a hotkey with backslash in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create a hotkey  using a backslash key (`\`). Namely, I would like to assign `Media_Prev` to Windows button + backslash. I have tried both `LWin & \::Media_Prev` and `#\::Media_Prev`. However, these do not work: it just normally sends the backslash character. In AutoHotkey's key history, I do see that both `\` and `LWin` register when I press this key combination.

Interestingly, something like  `LWin & c::Media_Prev` or `#v::Media_Prev` does work well, just not with the backslash character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, using AHK version 1.1.13.01

```
LWin & \:: run Notepad
```

you can also use scan codes - something like

```
SC15B & SC02B:: run Notepad
```

should have the same effect

reference: [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: The two options you suggested did not work. However, the following did work: `LWin & SC02B::Media_Prev`. I have edited your answer to include this information, hope you do not mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I successfully tested the following:

```
<#vk dc::Send {Media_Prev}
```

- `<` is Left key
- `#` is Windows key
- `VK DC` is virtual key number DC (you can find this code using AHK menu **View** > **Key History and Script Info**). With VK, the same key works regardless of active keyboard layout.

**Note:** Don't do `LWin & key` or `Ctrl & key` etc... `&` has a bit different meaning. For the above purpose AHK provides prefixes as shown above, e.g. `^b` or `#F1` etc. See AHK help on *Remapping Keys and Buttons*

Comment: I am afraid this does not work on my system. Interestingly, when I press this key combination, in **Key History and Script Info** I do see `Media_Prev` but it has no effect, track does not change. Same thing on another laptop.